# Registration For website Resets instead of entering into database

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I am making a registration form for my website. I believe I have all my code correct, but when I press submit it just clears the page. Any idea what I am doing wrong. I believe that I have the right variables in place but something just isnt working. If you have any ideas I would greatly appreciate it

```html
<?php
// Include config file
include("includes/config.php");
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $email = $fname = $lname = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $email_err = $fname_err = $lname_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

//setting the initial permissions to default of 1 which mean they have nothing. 
$permissions = 1;
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // If this happends you are disconnected and I will kill myself. 
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    // Validate firstname
    if(empty(trim($_POST["fname"]))){
        $fname_err = "Please enter your first name.";}
        // Validate firstname
    if(empty(trim($_POST["lname"]))){
        $lname_err = "Please enter your last name.";}
        // Validate firstname
    if(empty(trim($_POST["email"]))){
        $email_err = "Please enter your email.";}

    

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 8){
        $password_err = "Password must have at least 8 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }
    
    // If this goes off you havent put anything into the 
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($fname_err) && empty($lname_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, fname, lname, email, permissions) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password, $fname, $lname, $email, $permissions);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
 <?php 
 include('includes/header.php');
?>
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($email_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err; ?></span>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($fname_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $fname_err; ?></span>
            </div> 
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($lname_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $lname_err; ?></span>
            </div>              
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form> 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: did you check if the variables are set? i think your variables are override

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every request the variables are override because of this

```
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $email = $fname = $lname = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $email_err = $fname_err = $lname_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
```

please try to apply this on all variables

please remove this on input fields

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
```

then you can assign it on this block

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
     //add validation then set variables
     $email = $_POST["email"];
}
```